# Is it possible to preview github.com/shopspring/decimal values in VSCode during debugging?

Tags: go, decimal, vscode-debugger, delve

This is a preview of a normal `int64`/`float64` variable in Go in vscode during debugging.

[image]

And this is how it looks when using a variable from Decimal library.
[image]

If that would be possible then debugging would be so much easier. Right now, being a value is not possible without logs and if there are no logs you need to rebuild and restart the project.

Any ideas of how to achieve it - maybe a plugin or some kind of expression?
Or maybe someone knows how to write a plugin/extension for that?

Basically to see the value we need to call. var.String() function but it is not possible to call function during viscose debugging. Or I just don't know how.

I have been using this arbitrary-precision package called Decimal (https://github.com/shopspring/decimal) for years and this was a pain and I finally want to make it work.

Yes, in this example you can click expand 3 times then take the value 2345454 and take exp:-3 and just put a dot there in your head and get 2345.453 but this is not ideal and I think it does not always work anyway, especially hard with below-zero values.

Comment: You could try adding a watch expression, calling its `String()` method: `call fff.String()`. It does not always work for me though (it works for types in the standard lib such as `big.Int`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expand @icza's comment.

`call fff.String()` does not work for `github.com/shopspring/decimal` on my computer. It errors with:

```
(dlv) call t.String()
> main.main() ./main.go:20 (PC: 0x49ecbf)
Command failed: write out of bounds
```

My system is `linux/amd64`. And I think it does not work on all 64bit systems.

There is a bug in the current version of `dlv` (1.20.2). I just filed a [bug report](https://github.com/go-delve/delve/issues/3364) and sent a [fix](https://github.com/go-delve/delve/issues/3365).

**Update**:

The fix has been merged. You can update `dlv` to get this fix:

```
$ go install github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv@master
```

Here is the result with this fix:

[image: vs-code debug view]

Comment: This is amazing. I have been living with this for years. I have to say that this is kinda freaky but I have been using Decimal everywhere even if I can just use float64. So living without being able to  preview it was very painful. And you not only pointed out a problem but reported it and solved it too. Brilliant! I truly wish you all the best in work and in life.